# why SaveChanges invokes when i'm debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am developing application using Entity Framework.

When i'm in debugging mode my test values are saved into database when i exit debugging even if i'm not hitting SaveChanges method.

Why is this happening?

I spent 4 hours trying to figure it out, but had no luck....

Even if i have my breakpoint at the start of the action, and i exit debugger right away - data still persisting...

Comment: You have a bug in your code. Handle `SavingChanges`, put a breakpoint there, and look at the call stack when it stops.

Comment: what should i look for there?

Comment: You look for the thing in the call stack which caused `SaveChanges` to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that debugger continues execution of code even when it is on a breakpoint, and if there is no errors in my code it will apply changes to the database.

one way to avoid this - is to add preprocessor to your code like this:

```
#if !DEBUG 
      context.SaveChanges();
#endif
```

I was not able to track it via SavingChanges method, as am not really sure what should i look for there, there are so many different things, and i didn't have enough time to stuck on that.